# Horizontal lift of a piecewise smooth path

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, fiber-bundles

Let $M$ be the total space of a fibre bundle with a base a compact simply connected manifold $X$.  Using local coordinates and a partition of unity I was able to construct a riemannian metric $g_M$ such that $\pi:(M,g_M)\rightarrow (X,g_X)$ is a riemannian submersion. Then this riemannian metric $g_M$ will naturally define an horizontal distribution . However are we able to do the horizontal lift of a piecewise smooth path on $X$ which is uniquely defined provided we give the initial point ?

Any help or reference for this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does $M$ have compact fibers? If not, then it will only be possible to lift paths locally.

Comment: I guess I could assume that . Can you give me a reference for that result? @Kajelad

Comment: I don't know of a source, but it's easy to come up with counterexamples: for instance, the ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=1+y^2$ does not have solutions defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, so it corresponds to a counterexample on the bundle $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$.